# All File Descriptions from Multiple Value Field Showing Up for Each File in Views

Tags: 7, views, files, entities

I hit a little snag setting up this View for uploaded documents. I use a multi-uploader field to upload two files to an Entity. I've added descriptions for each file. When I try and display this in views, this is what I get:

**Name**
filename1
filename2

**Description**
filedesc1, filedesc2
filedesc1, filedesc2

It should be:

**Description**
filedesc1
filedesc2

The Description is a multiple value field, I'm assuming this is just spitting out array values for each record. Is there a way to step through this field so that the correct descriptions line up to the correct File Name?

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the results in the "Multiple Field Settings" to just one value?

Comment: Volker- I did try that, I set it to show 1 value starting at 0 (I'm guessing that's the index of the array its starting at). Then I just get the first file description over and over again.